# Looping over nested dictionary and delete if condition is not met (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of nested dictionaries:

```
[{'a': 1,
  'b': 'string',
  'c': [{'key1': 80,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4033},
        {'key1': 324,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4034,
         'key4': 1}]},
 {'a': 1,
  'b': 'string',
  'c': [{'key1': 80,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4033},
        {'key1': 324,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4034,
         'key4': 1,
         'key5': 2}]}]
```

Please not that the values of key `c` is a list of dictionaries again.
Now I want to filter out from this list all dictionaries with key `c`, that do not contain `key1`, `key2`, `key3` & `key4`.

I thought of looping first over the first, second, and so on `dict` in the list, and then looping over the nested `dict`s that have `c` as a key. Then, if the `dict` inside `c` does not meet my requirement, I delete it.

Therefore my code would be:

```
for j in range(len(mydict)):
    for i in range(len(mydict[j]["c"])):
        if not all (k in mydict[j]["c"][i] for k in ("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4")):
            del(mydict[j]["c"][i])
```

But I am getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` error. Where is my mistake?

My desired output would be:

```
[{'a': 1,
  'b': 'string',
  'c': [{'key1': 324,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4034,
         'key4': 1}]},
 {'a': 1,
  'b': 'string',
  'c': [{'key1': 324,
         'key2': 'string',
         'key3': 4034,
         'key4': 1,
         'key5': 2}]}]
```

Comment: Add your desired output please, not just a rough description of what you are expecting your code to do.

Comment: From above dictionary, which type of output you want ?? so please add your desire output in your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with `for i in range(len(mydict[j]["c"])):` you are iterating the lists in the dict while at the same time removing from those lists. Instead, you can replace the inner loop with a list comprehension:

```
for d in mydict:
    d['c'] = [d2 for d2 in d['c']
                 if all(k in d2 for k in ("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to have another option:

```
keep = {'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'}
for h in mydict:
    h['c'] = [ e for e in h['c'] if len(keep - set(e.keys())) == 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted another perspective on it:

```
def remove_keys(mydict):
    mydict2 = mydict
    keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
    for xIndex, x in enumerate(mydict):
        for yIndex, y in enumerate(x['c']):
            if not all(key in y.keys() for key in keys):
                del mydict2[xIndex]['c'][yIndex]
    return mydict2
```

Returns a new dictionary with the modifications.